# Is this textbook written in LaTeX?

Tags: book-design, books

Consider the extract from Young & Freedman's *University Physics* below. The design does not immediately look very TeX-like. However, since it is written by physicists, you would think this was the natural program for them to use. So the question is, *could* this have been written in LaTeX using some highly advanced layout settings? And do you think it is?

**A side question:** How would you reproduce this layout?

[image: Young and Freedman]

Comment: Does the book feature a colophon that mentions how it was typeset?

Comment: No, nothing at all. Just a long list of contributors and copyright stuff.

Comment: If you have a pdf file check under properties. This gives you enough details to determine the program that produced it. Highly unlikely it was typeset with LaTeX, but you never know:)

Comment: Usually, you would be right. But not this time. They removed all information like "application" and "PDF producer."

Comment: But I don't see any particular parts of the design that seem impossible to reproduce in LaTeX at all.

Comment: It doesn't ‘look TeX-like’ just because most LaTeX users stick to the default layout/fonts. There is no such thing as a TeX-like look, in my opinion, there's only laziness or a disinterest for a truly personal layout.

Comment: Totally agreed, yet some choices have been made to change standard settings to something which looks very strange from a design perspective. For instance, equation numbers use another font than equations and text --- I cannot see why any designer would *actively* change the default settings to this.

Comment: Or actually, I think there is something called "TeX-like", namely those layouts that are easy to produce in TeX. Some are easy, because they use features that TeX is good at, others are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be done by Acrobat Distiller. In every case, you may send a polite mail to the publisher and will get the info for sure. Your question on how to reproduce this is too broad for this site.

[image]

Comment: This solution was brought to you by http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html

Comment: However, Distiller can be used as a PDF printer for document manipulation, so the original document can be in LaTeX.

Comment: @yo' I had the same thought. I am using Distiller to process DVIs, for example. I guess, the "mail-to-publisher" part of my answer is the most valid one.

Comment: But if it *had* been written in LaTeX, then the designers must have made many *very* strange changes in the layout compared to standard TeX. For instance, why do the equation numbers have another font than the equations? I do not think that would be easy to justify from a design perspective.

Comment: With Lua- or XeLaTeX this would not be more difficult than in some Acrobat tool. The books looks like a lot of work in every case.

Comment: distiller just means whatever typesetter was used it produced Postscript, so doesn't address the question of what system that was.

Comment: @Gaussler I think it can have sense to use the same font for equation labels and figure labels. I think this is the case, but bold numbers for the figure captions.

Answer (score 3):

this book was written with latex or lyx:

1- the question and answer was written with tcolorbox and multicolumn:

```
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newcounter{example}
\colorlet{colexam}{green!45!black}
\newtcolorbox[use counter=example]{myexample}{%
70
empty,title={\colorbox{green!45!black}{\textcolor{white}{Example \thetcbcounter}\textcolor{green!45!black}{\thinspace text text text}},attach boxed title to top left,
boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=2pt,top=4pt,
overlay={\draw[colexam,line width=2pt]
([yshift=-1pt]frame.north west)--([yshift=-1pt]frame.north east);}},
coltitle=colexam,fonttitle=\Large\bfseries,
before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=3mm,top=4pt,
breakable,pad at break*=0mm,vfill before first,
overlay unbroken={\draw[colexam,line width=1pt]
([yshift=-1pt]title.north east)--([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=-1pt]title.north-|frame.east)
--([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south east)--(frame.south west); },
overlay first={\draw[colexam,line width=1pt]
([yshift=-1pt]title.north east)--([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=-1pt]title.north-|frame.east)
--([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south east); },
overlay middle={\draw[colexam,line width=1pt] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north east)
--([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south east); },
overlay last={\draw[colexam,line width=1pt] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north east)
--([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south east)--(frame.south west);},%
}
\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myexample}
```

2- the bold and red Caption:

```
    \usepackage[labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon,textformat=simple,justification=justified,font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=red,bf},
textfont={color=black}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can design your book like this book by LyX program which built over LaTeX, the question and answer in your image design by `tcolorbox` package, with `multicolumn` package.
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox
look page 71.

You can see the GPL physics book here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ohodquizgame/files/Books/

[image]

Comment: page 71 is a table with graphics inside, do you want me to include a small image of it ? apart from that does LyX provide really interface for two column output on part of the page, etc... like in OP ?

Comment: page 71 in tcolorbox manual not in physics book:

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox

Comment: ah ok, page 71 in tcolorbox manual.